# Get image from SP mapped folder in code

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I'm trying to get an image in C#. The image is in a SP mapped folder. I know I have the url right because when I write it in the browser the image shows up. But when I try getting it by using Image.FromFile(url) I get a FileNotFound Error. This is what I'm doing:

```
Image image = Image.FromFile(@"/_layouts/15/images/Project/x-mark-3-xxl.png");
```

As I've said, the link works in the browser (https://servername/_layouts/15/images/Project/x-mark-3-xxl.png) but when I try to get that Image (System.Drawing) it gives me an error. Perhaps I need to do something else? My goal is getting the image and adding it to an ASP GridView.

Answer (score 1):

You could use WebClient class to download image and then MemoryStream to read it:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
byte[] bytes = wc.DownloadData("https://servername/_layouts/15/images/Project/x-mark-3-xxl.png");
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
```